# QGIS and autocomplete

Tags: qgis

I have a point layer to collect plant species. My problem is I have more than 200 Latin names in a separate list to do a `value relation` for this attribute.

Autocomplete when I add a point works, but only with the first letters.
Is it possible to have autocomplete "anywhere"?

For example, if I write `vic`, I would have`Vicky` and also `Ludovic` in the drop-down list?
This would be useful, cause my drop-down list is a combination like this: `Common name (Latin name)`. For some species, I remember only the Latin name, but I'm not able to find them with autocomplete.

Comment: Potentially your solution is in this question:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407104/qgis-autofill-of-data-attribute-field-not-working

I had a similar problem a while ago.

Comment: Not sure to understand... I don't want to add a value in a list? I just want to find in a list of more than 200 names a solution to find the correct specie with autocomplet. If I tape "Picea", I have a list of all the "Picea" in my drop-down list...OK! But I can't type "cea" to have all the species than contain "cea" in there name.

Comment: I did a separate plugin which used a json file relation like `layer_name` - `field_name` - `list_of_values`. Plugin has a search line, values combobox and button to change value in field. By using python you can filter out values from list and set a new value in field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot search for part of a value with the `Value Relation` widget. This is currently not supported. See feature request [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43457).

Answer (score 4):

It works for me, if I use the “normal” relations which are found under `project properties`. In your case, when combining English and scientific names, I would recommend you to create a third row in the species list, which aggregates both names (separated with a `|` or similar) and use this row as the `display expression` in the `relation reference`. This way you should be able to type whatever part of the names you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this small plugin in python console.
Let there be a layer called `polygons`. This layer have some fields including `name` which should contain a list of specific values.

When you launch the script you will see this thing:

[image]

As I said in a comment section of question: there is a user input line, combobxes (fields, values) and button to set a new value.

Once you select a new layer, field+values comboboxes are changing. Once you change field, a value list is updating accroding to its existance in sample dict. And once you enter something in a line box, values box will filter its content to the closest  values to user print.

[image]

After you press button `Set value`, script will update all selected features' field according to what you select in values combobox. If nothing  was found in combobox, field attribute will be updated with a user printed value.

You can change `values_dict` according to your layer and test it.

```
# sample values dict
values_dict = {
    "polygons":{
        "name": [
            "Panthera pardus orientalis",
            "Diceros bicornis", 
            "Pongo pygmaeus", 
            "Gorilla gorilla diehli",
            "Eretmochelys imbricata", 
            "Rhinoceros sondaicus",
            "Crocodile"
        ]
    }
}

class filler(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setSpacing(10)
        
        # variables
        self.current_layer = None
        self.fields_data = []
        self.values_data = []

        # widgets
        self.line_search = QLineEdit()
        self.combo_fields= QComboBox()
        self.combo_values= QComboBox()
        self.value_change = QPushButton('Set value')
        
        # gui setup
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.line_search, 0, 1, 1, 5)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.combo_fields, 2, 1, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.combo_values, 2, 3, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.value_change, 3, 1, 1, 5)

        # actions
        iface.currentLayerChanged.connect(self.get_active_layer)
        self.combo_fields.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update_field_data)
        self.line_search.textChanged.connect(self.filter_values)
        self.value_change.clicked.connect(self.calculate)

        self.get_active_layer()
        self.show()


    def get_active_layer(self):
        # get an active layer and load its fields and related values
        if iface.activeLayer().type() == QgsVectorLayer.VectorLayer:
            self.current_layer = iface.activeLayer()
            self.fields_data = self.current_layer.fields().names()
            self.combo_fields.clear()
            self.combo_fields.addItems(self.fields_data)
            self.update_field_data()
            
    
    def update_field_data(self):
        # get field values load in combobox
        cur_index = self.combo_fields.currentIndex()
        cur_index = cur_index if cur_index!=-1 else 0
        self.combo_values.clear()
        field_data = values_dict.get(self.current_layer.name(), {})
        self.values_data = field_data.get(self.fields_data[cur_index],[])
        self.combo_values.addItems(self.values_data)
    

    def filter_values(self):
        # filtering values by user text
        value_str = self.line_search.text().lower()
        if not value_str:
            self.combo_values.clear()
            self.combo_values.addItems(self.values_data)
            return
        
        # dict like {"sample data value": ["Sample Data Value": ["sample", "data", "value"]]}
        splitted_values = {n.lower(): [n, n.lower().split()] for n in self.values_data if value_str in n.lower()}
        
        # sorting findings
        # if init value starts with user value => wrd_index is 1
        # if part of init value starts with user value => wrd_index is 2
        # if user value within init value => wrd_index is 3
        sorted_data = {}
        for key, value in splitted_values.items():
            if key.startswith(value_str):
                wrd_index = 1
            starting_v = [v.startswith(value_str) for v in value[1]]
            if any(n for n in starting_v):
                wrd_index = 2
            else:
                wrd_index = 3
            sorted_data[value[0]] = wrd_index
        
        # sorting findings by wrd_index and loading them into combobox
        sorted_findings = [v[0] for v in list(sorted(sorted_data.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]))]
        self.combo_values.clear()
        self.combo_values.addItems(sorted_findings)


    def calculate(self):
        # updating features with new value
        # works only if features are selected

        list_selected = self.current_layer.selectedFeatureIds()
        if not list_selected:
            QMessageBox.information(None, "Warning", 'Select features to update') 
            return
        
        # if nothing was found the user input is taken
        new_value = self.combo_values.currentText() if self.combo_values.currentText() else self.line_search.text()
        field_id = self.combo_fields.currentIndex()
        self.current_layer.startEditing()
        for fid in list_selected:
            self.current_layer.changeAttributeValue(fid, field_id, new_value)


app = filler()
```

Comment: Not sure to see how to use it when you digitalize a lot of feature with around 12 different  attributes?!?

Comment: @katagena scroll through each field and type text that will be searched in values dict. You can extend dict with another fields and values. I suppose it could be the way faster than manual typing in each field.